# HTML5 video doesn't work in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have opened many sites that use HTML5 video in the emulator ( android 2.3.3 and android 5 ) but it doesn't work: I can hear the audio but the video doesn't appear. On my smartphone ( samsung s5 with android 5 ) it works.

So why html5 video tag doesn't work well in the emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking if the encoding format is compatible with the emulator version and the `android` requirements. That can be done here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Also remember to check beneath the initial grid for the encoding requirements.

To read more about HTML5 videos in android:
http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/

Hope this helps you understand the problem better. Try and look around on his site for more of his blogs posts on the different subjects. He seems pretty competent.

Comment: unfortunately the answer can also be that the emulator sucks, I'm afraid

Comment: updated the answer, hope it will help you out because I do not have a deeper knowledge about the emulator, because all my own testing on android is on a physical device or in worst case scenario, a VM not hosted by my IDE

Comment: So don't you test your apps on older android devices ?

Comment: not really no :) mostly because my projects have never been released to anyone - but at work, we host a VM that handles the task of being a test server for the older versions of android